# Thread management in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need a solution that allows to set a capped number of thread running on the system and that optimizes memory and CPU usage (for example, the size of memory will not grow over the known total thread stack memory), etc.

Is there a native Java technology for that or a third party library?

Thanks

Comment: Apart from using a fixed size thread pool, you may be trying to place restrictions on the use of thread you don't need to.  Can you explain why you want to enforce these restrictions and what you expect to happen if these limits are reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread stack size is constant in Java, so you don't have to worry about individual thread size growing without bound.

If you're writing code that wants to do things in many threads and you want to make sure you don't consume more than a given number of threads, you can use something like a [fixed thread count executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29).

Do you want to limit the number of threads of a program that you have no other control over? You probably need to do something special for each operating system. Linux, for example, has no per-process thread limits (only a global limit common to all processes).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you search for something called "process accounting" but just for threads. Within one JVM this is not possible, every thread can consume all the memory of your JVM, and if it sets its priority to the highest value it will propably also "steal" CPU from the other threads in your JVM.